# Would you tell me which blue flower is this in this garden?

Tags: identification

I am curious about the blue / purple flower.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have posted the same photo in two posts, was that intentional ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the foreground we see what appears to be Staghorn Sumac in full fall/autumn colours, so this indicates late in the year and in a temperate zone. Often found in this type of location and copiously flowering in the fall in blue colour is the wild aster. They are composite daisy like flowers and about 2-3 feet in height with a stiff stem  at this time of year.

It's a good place to start, but if on close examination you doubt this suggestion then by all means post more detail when available.